# How to use SubHeaders in Material UI Select Menu

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I am struggling on how to properly set up a long list of [Menu Items](https://material-ui.com/api/menu-item/) on a [Select control](https://material-ui.com/components/selects/) that uses sticky SubHeaders. The problem is that when the items scroll they obscure the subheaders.

I looked at the Material UI examples of [grouped Select items](https://material-ui.com/components/selects/#grouping) as a start. I wanted behavior that looked like the Material UI example with [pinned subHeader Lists](https://material-ui.com/components/lists/#pinned-subheader-list).

Here is a [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/failed-select-menu-subheaders-oqmy2?file=/demo.js) of what I'm trying.

Below is a snippet of my code:

```
<Select
        className={classes.root}
        MenuProps={{ className: classes.menu }}
        value="Pick one"
        onChange={e => {}}
      >
        {subHeaders.map(header => (
          <li key={header}>
            <ul>
              <ListSubheader>{header}</ListSubheader>
              {items.map(item => (
                <MenuItem key={item} value={item}>
                  {item}
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </li>
        ))}
      </Select>
```

Here is a snapshot of the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the **Select** component we can even reproduce the behavior with some corrections. **But it won't work for you**. The **Select** component ***does not expect items nested within your child's elements***. That way, we will never be able to ***identify the element that is selected***.

Alternatively, we have the [**Autocomplete**](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#grouped) component. 
It can better supply what you need.

[image]

Regarding the example you provided, we can do something, but again, **we will not be able to maintain the state of the selected item.**
To achieve the same behavior as the list, we need to apply the same behavior to the list that the Menu will render. 
Select will render a Menu that inherits List, so we can apply the same behavior as the list example through the prop [MenuListProps](https://material-ui.com/api/menu/#props) property.

I applied the fixes to your example

[image: Edit Button]

I hope it helps.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean with the inability to get the actual selected item. I'll take a look at autocomplete. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make a working solution of Material-ui select with and sticky MenuItems.

use MaterialUI MenuItem instead of all the `<li> <ul> <ListSubheader>`

```
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    const [value, setValue] = useState();
    
    const onToggle = () => {
        setIsOpen((prev) => !prev);
      };
    
    const onClose = () => {
        setIsOpen(false);
      };
    
    const _onChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<{ value: unknown }>) => {
        const valueToSelect = event.target.value as Value;
        if (
          isResetSeletced(valueToSelect) ||
          (multiple
            ? !valueToSelect.length ||
              valueToSelect.length < minSelections ||
              (valueToSelect as string[]).some((option) => !option)
            : !valueToSelect?.length && minSelections > 0)
        ) {
          return;
        }
        event.persist();
        onChange(valueToSelect);
      };
    
      const renderValue = (selected: any) => {
        if (!selected.length) {
          return '';
        }
        if (multiple) {
          const isReachedLimit = selected.length > MAX_SELECTIONS;
          const hiddenTags = isReachedLimit ? (
            <span>+{value.length - MAX_SELECTIONS}</span>
          ) : null;
          const selectionsToShow = isReachedLimit
            ? selected.slice(0, MAX_SELECTIONS)
            : selected;
          return (
            <StyledTagsContainer>
              <Tags values={selectionsToShow} onRemoveTag={onRemoveTag} />
              {hiddenTags}
            </StyledTagsContainer>
          );
        }
        return selected;
      };


  const resetMenuItem = secondaryOptions?.map((resetItem, index) => {
    return (
      <MenuItem
        key={resetItem.value + index}
        onClick={() => {
          resetItem.onClick();
        }}
        isLast={!index}
        isSelected={
          resetItem.value === resetSelected?.value ||
          resetItem.value === value ||
          (multiple && resetItem.value === value[0])
        }
        value={resetItem.value}
        icon={<RadioIcon />}
      >
        {resetItem.text}
      </MenuItem>
    );
  });
    
    
    <Select
        displayEmpty
        onClose={onClose}
        value={value}
        onChange={_onChange}
        renderValue={renderValue}
        open={isOpen}
      >
        {menuItems}

        <div style={{ position: 'sticky', bottom: 0 }}>
          {resetMenuItem}
        </div>

    </Select>
```

Comment: hm, can you show this in a code sandbox? It looks like your sample is missing some things like `isREsetSeletced`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
To make it work you need to have only one list.
The list must be something like:

```
[
  {
     value,
     text,
     isParent (is section)
  }
]
```

IMPORTANT! It has to be sorted like this:
Parent 1 - Child 1 (parent 1) - Child 2 (parent 1) - Parent 2 - Child 1 (parent 2)....

Then:

```
const array = [
  { text: 'parent 1', isParent: true }, 
  { text: 'child 1 parent 1', value: 2, isParent: false }, 
  { text: 'child 2 parent 1', value: 3, isParent: false }, 
  { text: 'parent 2', isParent: true }, 
  { text: 'child 1 parent 2', value: 4, isParent: false }, 
  { text: 'child 2 parent 2', value: 5, isParent: false }, 
]

<Select>
  {array.map(option => {
    if(option.isParent)
      return (
        <ListSubheader>
          {option.text}
        </ListSubheader>
      )
    else
      return (
        <MenuItem 
          value={option.value}
        >
          {option.text}
        </MenuItem>
      )
  })}
</Select>
```